# Android Voice changing app need help in storing changed voice

Tags: android, save, record, voice

In one of my app i need to change sound frequency like it should be in thick voice for that i have use
[THIS LINK](http://android-er.blogspot.hk/2012/06/implement-voice-changer-by-changing.html)

The above link code works fine for me...

While playing audio it change voice

My problem is HOW TO STORE THIS CHANGED VOICE?

this is method which play voice with changing in voice

```
void playRecord(){

  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

        int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE/Byte.SIZE;

  int bufferSizeInBytes = (int)(file.length()/shortSizeInBytes);
  short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

  try {
   InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
   BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
   DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

   int i = 0;
   while(dataInputStream.available() > 0){
    audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
    i++;
   }

   dataInputStream.close();

   int sampleFreq = (Integer)spFrequency.getSelectedItem();

   AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
     AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
     sampleFreq,
     AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
     AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
     bufferSizeInBytes,
     AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

   audioTrack.play();
   audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);


  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

How can i store this clip in SDCARD? this is what i need is

In short i need all this thing to share that changed voice clip.. how i can i do this?

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and searched a lot and could not find a solution, But I came to a solution is to record the file with natural sound and save it in the phone and then used and called with the change Hz again ..

**This Is Code StartRecord And Save it in Storage Device..**

```
 private void startRecord() {

    AudioSavePathInDevice = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SarahaVoice";

    NameAudio = CreateRandomAudioFileName(5) + "Recording.mp3";

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), NameAudio, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    File file = new File(AudioSavePathInDevice, NameAudio);

    try {
        //file.createNewFile();

        //Upcasting
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        //Buffering (Get Temporary Space To Write File.. When Finished Writing File Removed Temporary Space)
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
        //Uses To Write Data Types Of Primitive Data In File
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

        int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(11025, 2, 2);

        short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

        AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(1, 11025, 2, 2,minBufferSize);

        audioRecord.startRecording();

        while(recording){
            int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++){
                dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
            }
        }
        if (!recording.booleanValue())
        {
            audioRecord.stop();
            audioRecord.release();
            dataOutputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**And Also Code To PlayRecord audio From Storage Device With Change Hz..**

```
void playRecord() {

    audioTrack = null;

    String str = (String) spFrequency.getSelectedItem();

    File file = new File(AudioSavePathInDevice, NameAudio);

    int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE/Byte.SIZE;

    final int bufferSizeInBytes = (int)(file.length()/shortSizeInBytes);

    final short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

        int j = 0;
        while(dataInputStream.available() > 0){
            audioData[j] = dataInputStream.readShort();
            j++;

        }

        dataInputStream.close();
        if (str.equals(getString(R.string.normal)))
        {
            i = 11025;
        }
        if (str.equals(getString(R.string.monster)))
        {
            i = 8000;
        }
        if (str.equals(getString(R.string.chipmunk)))
        {
            i = 16000;
        }
        if (str.equals(getString(R.string.funny)))
        {
            i = 9000;
        }
        if (str.equals(getString(R.string.bee)))
        {
            i = 13000;
        }

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(3,i,2,2,bufferSizeInBytes,1);

        audioTrack.play();
        audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Ask yourself what they are Function CreateRandomAudioFileName() ^_^ This Function Create Random text Its code is down..**

```
public String CreateRandomAudioFileName(int string){

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( string );

    int i = 0 ;
    while(i < string ) {

        stringBuilder.append(RandomAudioFileName.charAt(random.nextInt(RandomAudioFileName.length())));

        i++ ;
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

**God be with you :)**